# Calculating a Score via Maximum Value of one column depending on another in a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, list, csv, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes (former csv files) which I need to format. I did all that in a formula. Now I want to calculate a score for a value in each data frame. 
Each data frame looks like this:

```
Country Year [Indicator]
Afghanistan 2007 10.000
Andorra 2008 18.000
Andorra 2009 20.000
Anguilla 2007 15.000
Anguilla 2009 1.000
```

...

So there is an indicator for each country and each year (Some countries do not have data for every year)

I now want to add a new column with a score per year. So in 2007 the country with the highest score gets a 10 and the others get less.
I calculate this via: 
Score = (Value of the country in a certain year / maximum value of all countries in this year) * 10

I've done that like this:

```
ImportGER_max <- aggregate(Import ~ Year, data = ImportGER_2, max)
ImportGER_max[which(ImportGER_max$Year == 2007),2]
x <- 2006

while(x < 2016) {x <- x+1;
ImportGER_2$ImportGERRank[ImportGER_2$Year == x] <- ImportGER_max[which(ImportGER_max$Year == x),2]}

ImportGER_2$ImportGERScore <- (ImportGER_2$Import/ImportGER_2$ImportGERRank) * 10
```

This is surely not the most elegant way, but it works. Alas, this is only for one specific dataset, but I want it to work on a list of dataframes.

My code for creating the list and formatting the csv files is as follows:

```
mycsv <- dir(pattern="*csv")
n <- length(mycsv)
mylist <- vector("list", n)

for(i in 1:n) mylist[[i]] <- read.csv(mycsv[i], header = T, sep = ";")

mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) {

  df_join <- join(x, translate, by = c("Country"), type = c("left"), match = "all")
  df_join2 <- join(template, df_join, by = c("Standard"), type = c("left"), match = "all")
  df_join2$Country <- NULL
  df_join2[,3] <- as.numeric(as.character(df_join2[,3]))
  df_join2[is.na(df_join2)] <- -10000

  return(df_join2)
  })
```

I do not manage to include the code for calculating the score in the formula for all the data frames.

edit: I use the plyr package for the join function.

edit2: I found a solution now myself, see the code below if anyone is interested:

```
>     mycsv <- dir(pattern="*csv")
>     n <- length(mycsv)
>     mylist <- vector("list", n)
>     
>     
>    
>     for(i in 1:n) mylist[[i]] <- read.csv(mycsv[i], header = T, sep = ";")
>     
>     mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) {
>       
>       df_join <- join(x, translate, by = c("Country"), type = c("left"), match = "all")
>       df_join2 <- join(template, df_join, by = c("Standard"), type = c("left"), match = "all")
>       df_join2$Country <- NULL
>       df_join2[,3] <- as.numeric(as.character(df_join2[,3]))
>       df_join2[is.na(df_join2)] <- -10000
>       colnames(df_join2)[3] <- "Indicator"
>       df_joinMAX <- aggregate(Indicator ~ Year, data = df_join2, max)
>       
>       x <- 2006
>       
>       while(x < 2020) {x <- x+1;
>       df_join2$Rank[df_join2$Year == x] <- df_joinMAX[which(df_joinMAX$Year == x),2]}
>       
>       df_join2$Score <- (df_join2$Indicator/df_join2$Rank) * 10
>      
>       return(df_join2)
>       })
```

Again, I bet there are better solutions but for a start, this gives exactly the output I wanted.

Comment: I edited my post, I'm using the plyr package.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
# Load library
library(dplyr)

# Calculate score
reformat.df <- function(file.name){
  df <- read.csv(file.name, header = T, sep = ";")

  df %>% 
    group_by(.[[2]]) %>% 
    mutate(score = 10 * .[[3]]/max(.[[3]])) %>% 
    ungroup()
}

# Do for all CSV files
mylist <- lapply(as.list(dir(pattern = ".csv")), reformat.df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it does not seem to work. The problem is, that the Indicator column does not have the same name in every df.. and it doesn't seem to work with a reference like [,3]. And why do I need to load the csv-files again? I put them in the mylist List already. Sorry I'm really new to R

Comment: Does it have the same position in every file? And you don't need to load them again. I'm just doing the loading and reformatting in one go.

Comment: Ah ok. Yes, it is always the third column of each df.

Comment: I've edited my answer using column position assuming indicator is always in the third column and year is in the second.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me but it's not working. This is the error message I get: "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument "..1" is missing, with no default." What does it mean? And how does this mutate argument work? In the end there should be a score of each country for each year

Comment: Can you run `reformat.df` using one file name and post the contents of that file so that I can reproduce the error?

Comment: I don't know what you mean? the structure of the df is always  in three columns               
 Standard Year         Indicator 1
Land 1             2007 194086
Land 1          2008 394327
Land 1          2009 313706
Land 1          2010 356884
Land 1          2011 392279
Land 2          2007 377969
Land 3             2007        216681